# htaccess несуществующие подпапки

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер

Есть проблема:

В корне есть папка json, в ней несколько папок, там лежат json файлы. Когда запрашиваю любой не существующий файл из существующих подпапок - возвращает, как положено 404:
`http://mysite.com/json/REALFOLDER/BLABLA/some.json`  -- имеем `404`

Если же запросить файл так:
`http://mysite.com/json/BLABLA/some.json`  -- выдаст `500 Internal Server Error`

```
RewriteEngine On
rewriterule ^(.*)json/(.*)$ json/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
Options All -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрещает просмотр содержимого папки

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Замени на это

```
Options -Indexes
```

Или можешь закомментировать

```
#Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: К  сожалению нет. Ни изменение, ни комментирование проблему не решает. К тому же мне нужно запретить просмотр содержимого. Да и этот запрет возвращал бы 403 - доступ запрещен.